# How do you pass a 2d array as a param in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, arrow-functions

I'm trying to access a specific element in an array, but I'm only getting the first one. Any help with pointing out my error is appreciated.

```
let testArr = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]];
const printArr = (someArr, i) => alert(someArr[i]);
printArr(testArr, [0][0]);
```

Expected Output

```
1
```

Actual Output

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: `testArr[0].join(", ")`

Comment: `[0][0]` is `0` so you are referencing in `alert` the first element of `testArr` which is `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: console.log([0][0])

Answer (score 3):

`[0][0]` is actually `0`. This is the same as

```
a = [0];
a[0] === [0][0]; // 0
```

What you want to actually do is unclear. If you just want to pass a value, just pass that value, rather than the array and index separately.

```
printArr(testArr[0][0]);
```

If, for whatever reason, you need the index and array passed separately, then you can pass the indies as an array:

```js
let testArr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, [8, 9], 10]
];
const printArr = (arr, indices) => console.log(indices.reduce((a, i) => a[i], arr));
printArr(testArr, [2, 1, 0]); // 8
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> printArr(testArr, [0][0]);
> ```

aproximates to:

```
const some_array = [0];
const second_arg = some_array[0]
printArr(testArr, second_arg);
```

You are passing `0` as the second argument.

You can't pass arbitrary bits of JS syntax around.

Use two arguments instead.

```js
let testArr = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]];
const printArr = (someArr, i, j) => alert(someArr[i][j]);
printArr(testArr, 0, 0);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for getting a special value.

```js
let testArr = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]];

const printArr = (someArr, fn) => console.log(fn(someArr));

printArr(testArr, array => array[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do it without casting array like numbers or similar.

```
let testArr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
];
const printArr = (someArr, arrNum, indNum) => someArr[arrNum][indNum];

printArr(testArr, 1, 0);
```